# Pass jQuery variable to PHP using POST method

Tags: php, jquery

I have a variable called `selectedText` that want to pass to PHP. I do a case according to which variable comes out as:

```
$(function(){
        $('#status_users').change(function () {
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        //alert(selectedText);
        switch ($('#status_users :selected').text()) {
                case 'Active':
                        $.post("ajax/readRecords_Status.php", {}, function (data, selectedText) {
                                $(".records_content").html(data);
                        });
                        break;
                case 'Inactive':
                        $.post("ajax/readRecords_Status.php", {}, function (data, selectedText) {
                                $(".records_content").html(data);
                        });
                        break;
                case 'Try':
                        $.post("ajax/readRecords_Status.php", {}, function (data, selectedText) {
                                $(".records_content").html(data);
                        });
                        break;
                case 'All':
                        $.post("ajax/readRecords.php", {}, function (data, selectedText) {
                                $(".records_content").html(data);
                        });
                        break;
                }
        });
});
```

Last case is run because not pass a variable and call another code

On php have:

```
$status_users = $_POST['selectedText'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` where register_status ='".$status_users"'" ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following

```
{selectedText:selectedText}
```

as second parameter in all requests. And remove second parameter from function.

Full code:

```
$(function(){
        $('#status_users').change(function () {
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        //alert(selectedText);
        switch ($('#status_users :selected').text()) {
                case 'Active':
                        $.post("ajax/readRecords_Status.php", {selectedText:selectedText}, function (data) {
                                $(".records_content").html(data);
                        });
                        break;
                case 'Inactive':
                        $.post("ajax/readRecords_Status.php", {selectedText:selectedText}, function (data) {
                                $(".records_content").html(data);
                        });
                        break;
                case 'Try':
                        $.post("ajax/readRecords_Status.php", {selectedText:selectedText}, function (data) {
                                $(".records_content").html(data);
                        });
                        break;
                case 'All':
                        $.post("ajax/readRecords.php", {selectedText:selectedText}, function (data) {
                                $(".records_content").html(data);
                        });
                        break;
                }
        });
});
```

Check [jQuery $.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for more.